# Disable scrolling by hook

Tags: c++, windows, hook

I am currently writing an application which allows scrolling, without focusing windows. 
What I've done yet: I created a [LowLevelMouseHook](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644986%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). If the LowLevelMouseProc recieves a MouseWheel-message I am searching for the handle at the cursor-position and send scroll-messages to that handle.
The hook looks like this:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK MouseHookCallback(int code, WPARAM wparam, LPARAM lparam)
{
    if(code < 0)
        return CallNextHookEx(mouseHookInstance, code, wparam, lparam);

    if(UserMouseHookCallback != NULL)
    {
        UserMouseHookCallback(code, wparam, lparam);//scroll the hovered window here
        if(wparam == WM_MOUSEWHEEL)
            return -1;
    }

    return CallNextHookEx(mouseHookInstance, code, wparam, lparam);
}
```

As you can see, I am returing -1 if the message is a mousewheel-message. That should avoid scrolling the currently focused window(I don't want to scroll the focused window, I want to scroll the window which is hovered by the cursor). The problem is, that it does not cancel scrolling the focused window. So does anyone has an idea how to avoid scrolling the currently focused window? At the moment there are two windows which are getting scrolled. The one my mouse is hover and the one which is focused.

Please don't downvote my question and give me a chance. I am really doing my best but I am not able to find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution. It is very, very, very simple. Set `<requestedExecutionLevel  level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />` in your manifest or start it as administrator manually and it works :)